# Can't install debug version of my android application

Tags: android, installation

I wrote an android application in IDEA. When I used Debug-mode (connected to my device) - everything worked nice. But when I manually downloaded apk file to my phone and tried to install application - it said:

"**Installation failed**. *Reason for failture*: **This app is for testing only.** *Suggestion*: **install the official version of this app.**"

How to solve this problem?

PS: phone: Huawei p40 lite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this problem with clicking "Build -> Build APK" in IDEA.

It also can be solved via adding:

```
# Disble testOnly mode for Android Studio
android.injected.testOnly=false
```

in `gradle.properties` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use command:

> adb install -t your_apk